# Split string fixed width

Tags: r, string, split, splitstackshape

Sorry for this surely basic question, but I really couldn't find a clear answer:

I have a data frame I'm trying to split by a fixed number of characters

I'd previously been using:

```
data = cSplit(data, 'variable', sep="what to separate on", type.convert=FALSE)
```

...to split, but that causes issues if there are multiple instances of the "what to split on" in the data.

I want to split this names column by the first four characters (as splitting on "." causes issues for names with multiple "."

```
names
Mr. Joe Smith
Ms. Sarah A. Jones
Mr. Ryan P. Young
Ms. Chelsea White
```

Data

```
names <- c('Mr. Joe Smith', 'Ms. Sarah A. Jones', 'Mr. Ryan P. Young', 'Ms. Chelsea White')
```

Comment: If it's just the first four characters, maybe you can use `substr(x, 1,4)` and `substr(x, 5, nchar(x))`?

Comment: @Frank Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks for the simple tip for this R newbie!

Comment: Np, linking it to another question with a lot more alternatives.

Comment: this sounds like an xy problem. you can sub out the first `.` and split based on whatever you sub in `strsplit(sub('\\.\\s+', ';', names), ';')`